# What's the purpose of fromReflectedMethod and toReflectedMethod in JNI?

Tags: java, reflection, java-native-interface, ffi

I was reading the [JNI spec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/functions.html) and saw the [reflection support methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#reflection-support) section.

I don't quite understand what they are used for or what's the intended purpose. Since method ID is looked up using name and signature, don't we already have that information? And if we want to get more details, we can always write a java wrapper. So that cannot be the purpose I thought.

Comment: By the way, a replacement for JNI is on the way, previewed in Java 19: [*JEP 424: Foreign Function & Memory API (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/424)

Comment: I know about the JEP. It won't be coming to many LTS deployments or Android in near future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered in the JNI Specification.

Comment: Respectfully disagree. It only tells what it does, not where it will be useful. Please read my question again.